# Deserializing XML to C# child class

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

My XML :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response id="41cc788a-bc22-4ce0-8e1c-83bf49bbffed">
<message>Successfully processed the request</message>
<payload>Alive</payload>
</response>
```

My Classes :

```
[XmlRoot("response")]
[Serializable]
public abstract class ESBResponseBase<T>
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public string Message { get; set; }

    public T Payload { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot("response")]
[Serializable]
public class ESBResponseIsAlive : ESBResponseBase<string>
{
}
```

Note that if I don't have these classes on the child classes it throws an exception so it seems inheritance doesn't work with these.

My Serialization Code :

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof (ESBResponseIsAlive));
var esbResponseIsAlive = (ESBResponseIsAlive) serializer.Deserialize(result);
```

However when I serialize my object properties are null.

I think more than likely this is an issue with inheritance in classes used for serializing. It is possible to simply change the base class to the actual concrete class and use the Generic, but I preferred to have it strongly typed.

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, XMLSerializer is case-sensitive. My class now looks like the following and it works.

```
    [XmlAttribute("id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("message")]
    public string Message { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("payload")]
    public T Payload { get; set; }
```